# Changing a nested object in Redux using spread operators when the keys are dynamic?

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I am trying to store a nested object in redux, but I am using dynamic keys. Here is an example of what it would look like:

```
// In my Redux Reducer
const initialState = {
    stuff: {
        <dynamic_key>: { name: 'bob', title: 'mr' },
        <dynamic_key>: { name: 'eve', title: 'ms' },
        <dynamic_key>: { name: 'car', title: 'na' },
    },
};
```

So I have a redux state called `stuff` that should hold my nested objects.

However, I cannot correctly save my data. I know react states all have to be immutable, so I am using the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and `Object.assign()` to create a new object:

```
const reducer = ( state = initialState, action) => {
// ....
        case UPDATE:
            return { ...state, 
                stuff: { 
                    Object.assign({}, action.key, {
                        name: action.name,
                        title: action.title
                    })
                }
            };
// ....
}
```

The above is trying to create/update the entire `<dynamic_key>`, using `action.key` as the dynamic_key, `action.name` as the name, and `action.title` as the title.

An extra tidbit is that if `action.key` (the dynamic key) doesn't already exist in the redux store `stuff`, then it should be created rather than error out.

What am I doing wrong? I think I am not using `Object.assign()` correctly, or not using the spread operator correctly?

EDIT:

Here is my redux action:

```
export const update = s => ({ type: "UPDATE", payload: {key: s.key, name: s.name, title: s.title} });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Using object spread operator](https://redux.js.org/recipes/using-object-spread-operator)

It seems like in you're case, you've got a couple additionally unnecessary steps. If stuff is supposed to be an object that contains your dynamic keys/value pairs, then you should have:

```
stuff: Object.assign({}, state.stuff, {[action.key]: {etc...}})
```

OR

```
stuff: {
  ...state.stuff
  [action.key]: {name: etc...}
}
```

Keep in mind that every argument to Object.assign, must be an object. It seems like you are supplying the second argument a string.
I also assume you already have a compiler that allows you to safely use the object spread syntax.

EDIT: added state.stuff to both examples so as not to override previous properties.

Comment: I keep getting `undefined` as the key and `undefined` as the name and title. I double checked `action` is getting the correct values because I consoled them out. Also wouldn't the last example you have overwrite all the other keys I already have in my `stuff` store?

Comment: Yes, it would, but so will Object.assign unless you pass in the original stuff object as the second argument. You could do the same with the spread syntax:

stuff: {...originalStuff, [action.key]: etc....}

Also, where are you logging the values of action? Could you post the entire function?

Comment: I updated my post with my redux action. It basically just takes a parameter and then unloads it directly into the payload.

Comment: Can you post the entire reducer with your log that is confirming the contents of action?

Comment: Thanks, I reread the docs for spread ops and your comments really helped. The `...originalStuff` was the missing part, and I also had a missing closing bracket. I stuck with spread ops instead of Object.assign like you suggested.